C# modulo operation with decimal yields inconclusive result
I have a very quick question, based on the following C# code:
decimal _sampleCounter = 2100m;
decimal wrong = _sampleCounter % (30m / 2.3m);
decimal correct = 2100m % (30m / 2.3m);

Console.WriteLine(wrong);   // -> 13.043478260869565217391304320
Console.WriteLine(correct); // -> 0.0000000000000000000000000

The wrong result equals the result when using double instead of decimal.
The mathematically correct result is indeed exactly 0.
So what is happening here? Why is it not in both cases  0.0000...?
I could imagine that the compiler directly translates the variable "correct" to it's final value, but that doesn't explain why both results differ.
Best regards,
Philipp
Edit 1:
MY configuration is: Environment version: .NET 8.0.6 (8.0.6), Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22631.0. Default, IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints, EnableEditAndContinue, DisableOptimizations
Edit 2:
Well, the underlying problem is that I need to check when (30 / 2.3) divides 2100 without remainder. I have found a workaround by just doing the division and then checking whether the decimal places equal 0:
decimal.Compare((2100m / (30m / 2.3m)) % 1m,0m)

That does the job in my specific case. Any comments on that? In my case, this works also with double instead of decimal.

I'm getting 13.043478260869565217391304320 for both, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/JPIJ9k.  Can you share details about your environment + build configuration?

Here's how the compiler sees your code: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABM3AYVwG9NcL88EAWXAWQAoBKU8yjgEwFMBjKSABtcAfQDOEMAAdB3QgHsArjAAu3AE64AvLlQAGPWADc7DhR78huAO7r5MAObbRE6bIXK1mgKS5G2Q1wAel0AOmwwZhMMM0oLAQhhXnl1dT4VZ31A339AkKRwyOjTMwQUAE5GW3sHKMogkIBaAD5cFGxQvRpsGgB2AA4kADY9fqHygFYhidRe7HL2ruwkPRKOMsrk1PS6htwW3D1OgxPTs/PTkoBfTCugA=

Interestingly, I get 0.0000000000000000000000000 for both values using .NET Framework 4.7.4051.0, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/bvqezf.

decimal doesn't eliminate roundoff errors in mathematical calculations.  It simply solves the particular problem that Base 10 0.1 is repeating binary decimal and so cannot even be stored precisely in a base 2 double.  However (30m / 2.3m) = (300m / 23m) will be a repeating decimal in both Base 10 and Base 2 because 23 is prime.  So it's quite possible roundoff errors could cause your Mod operator to return something at the top of the range, rather than zero.  That being said I have no idea why there might be a difference from .NET Framework to Core.

(Also, "binary decimal " -- ugh, what an awful earful of a term.  Does anybody know anything better?  This answer uses "dyadic rational", this answer recommends "Base 2 Laurent series", and this answer throws up its hands and accepts the term.)
